# The Unicode support of Sublime text Build 3200 makes it impossible to select diacritics and visualise them separatedly

Tags: sublimetext3, rendering, arabic, diacritics, bidirectional

Two days ago, I updated Sublime text to Build 3200 in Linux Mint 18.3. The new changes include support for Unicode 11.0 and improved rendering of combining characters. In practice, I found that now Arabic diacritics are represented together with the base letter they go with, e.g. "بَ", and they cannot be selected separately, which is of course a major problem. Besides, a side effect of this is that a sequence of diacritics are rendered on top of the other, e.g. "ًٌٍَُِ". Obviously, this makes them impossible to be read, and also to be selected. The result in sublime is actually the same one that can be seen in here.

It is just impossible for me if I cannot select and see all Unicode characters separately, regardless if they are diacritics. Also, bi-directional support is a problem for me if it cannot be disabled, because I need to see the logical sequence of characters clearly. I checked Visual Studio Code, and although there it is possible to select all characters, apparently it comes will full bi-directional support, which makes my work harder.

Is there a way to fix the selection problem in Sublime? And also to see all characters represented one after the other, without being visually overlapped, in logical order? Is there any other editor available that can do this?

Frankly, it's very discouraging to see that no software knows how to handle this problem. A simple option to enable or disable bi-directionality and character combination would work for everyone.